# C# Looping and Terminating

Tags: c#, windows

I am currently teaching myself C# (starting very basic) but how can I code it so if the user types "yes" the program loops to the start or if the user types "no" the program ends?

My current code is

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        string UserName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("hello {0} what would you like me to do", UserName);
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line == "Time") Console.WriteLine("its {1}", UserName, System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
        if (line == "Date") Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Today);
        Console.WriteLine("anything else");
    }
```

Comment: use a loop structure such as while() .... or type "how to loop in C#" into a search engine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what you have:

```
do 
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello {0} what would you like me to do", UserName);
    if (line == "Time") Console.WriteLine("its {1}", UserName, System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
    if (line == "Date") Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Today);

    Console.WriteLine("anything else");
}
while (string.Equals(Console.ReadLine(), "yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

You need a [`do...while`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx) loop as you need to execute the loop at least once. (the `while` is executed after the `do`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while (true) {
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == "no") {
        break;
    }

    // do something with line
}
```

Comment: better check if(line != "yes")break;

Comment: yes, might be true, but this way is more flexible for other inputs: "Time", "Date", etc